# A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.

Tags: android, xml

I am developing a google maps app for android.

But, somehow my application crashes giving an error like :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.
```

This is what my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locations"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
  <permission android:name ="com.example.locations.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.locations.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAZhJllASbTnrFta8hj55shKydSi0ks824"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log:-

```
01-09 12:29:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(7448): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I am using google maps for this app
How can i resolve this?

Comment: Follow these instructions: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.  You need to add:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

As as child of the <application> element!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Missing the below in application tag of manifest. This ia new requirement as of updated google play services.

Check the topic Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest @

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Remove this

```
<permission android:name ="com.example.locations.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
```

not required

Comment: I removed the Permissions tag. That did resolve the error. DO i need to place the <meta-data> as is or replace google_play_services_version with something else

Comment: @user3146095 no. `<permission` not required from map api v2.  WHat is suggested is correct. Make sur you have the updated google play services. you can read the docs yourself. link also posted

Answer (score 10):

Google Map V2 add new feature in AndroidManifest.xml. You will need to add this metatag within `application` tag

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks for actually mentioning which section it needs to go in

Answer (score 6):

Try to add following meta-data tag on Manifest file it's working fine.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: what do I need to mention in the google_play_services_version??

Comment: This line only used to Android Studio you can used Eclipse that time used for google play service lib file

Answer (score 5):

As [Google Map V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) use use [Google Play services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) you need to keep it updated.
Latest google play services requires a `version` name, which is to be mentioned using `<meta-data .. />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`. This can be solved by both of the below ways_

**1.** Add following `meta-data` inside application tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

this value is there in your `Google Play services` library(***res -> values -> version.xml***)

**2.**  Directly add the version code like

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />
```

4030500 is version code which is stored inside

**google-play-services_lib>res>values>version.xml**

Like

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>
```

Comment: I using first method and it is working fine. I also cross checked my version from @integer/google_play_services_version and getting the desired result. But it is still crashing for some users on production. Any input on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning your project (select project>project tab>clean)

I solved my problem with this. Cleaning is the solution for most problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for permission:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.locations.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"                       android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
```

A  tag including the google services might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you **update** your **google play services** you need to **update your res/values tag** too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this line

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
in AndroidManifest.xml  <application>
```