# android google maps error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

i am trying to show a google maps on my app ,i am using google maps v2, i did all steps but i still have those errors and The app is crashed on launch ...
this the logcat :

```
    07-21 11:24:02.808: E/AndroidRuntime(592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmap/com.example.testmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testmap.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testmap-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testmap-2, /system/lib]]
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673): Process: com.example.testmap, PID: 673
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmap/com.example.testmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testmap.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testmap-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testmap-1, /system/lib]]
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2134)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testmap.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testmap-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testmap-1, /system/lib]]
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
07-21 11:38:26.698: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  ... 11 more
```

Mainctivity.java

```
package com.example.testmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

}

activitymain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testmap.MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment "/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

the manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<permission android:name="com.example.testmap.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="my key "/>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Referenced google play services? ALso meta tag in inside activity tag in manifest move it outside

Comment: yes referenced google play services , i moved meta tag outside activity bur it doesn't solved the error

Comment: cross check again if you have referenced google play services properly

Comment: yes i have referenced google play services

Comment: post how you have referenced coz i think something is wrong there

Comment: i have added the Google Play Services project into my Eclipse workspace and Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib

Comment: i have this error Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: check if you have different version of the jar files in your libs folder. copy android-support-v4.jar from the sdk/extras/support/android-support-v4.jar to the libs folder of both the library project and your project

Comment: i solved this problem but logcat give me new errors

Comment: 07-21 11:24:02.808: E/AndroidRuntime(592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmap/com.example.testmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testmap.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testmap-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testmap-2, /system/lib]]

Comment: @edit and post the full stacktrace again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Google Maps API "Error inflating class fragment"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039508/android-google-maps-api-error-inflating-class-fragment)