# how to solve IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

I am developping an app and i wanna display a google map v2 on activity but it doesn't show
this is a snippet form logcat

> 11-30 19:14:56.681: E/AndroidRuntime(6062):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.cultural/com.example.cultural.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>
> 11-30 19:14:56.681: E/AndroidRuntime(6062): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000
>   but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
>    element:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add this to your manifest application tag :

```
<application
   ... >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR KEY HERE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and see comment below or check this :

[Android Google Maps API "Error inflating class fragment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039508/android-google-maps-api-error-inflating-class-fragment?lq=1)

Comment: I check it and i have new problem 12-01 14:03:27.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cultural/com.example.cultural.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Check your layout XML. `<fragment>` starts with a small "f". If this didn't help, post the layout in the question.

Comment: here is my layout   <fragment 
        
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        />

Comment: I tried your xml but it doesnt solve my problem I got this bugs 12-03 13:39:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3544): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Class is not a View com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
12-03 13:39:15.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3544): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.view.View

Comment: Sorry, never used a map v2 in a Fragment before. All I know its available API 12+ only. Maybe using a MapView instead of a Fragment is the solution : <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView" />

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following **inside** the `<application>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: I check it and i have new problem 12-01 14:03:27.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cultural/com.example.cultural.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment