# Why autocomplete search dialog box not showing any suggestions?

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

I am following this tutorial http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/  

But when I try to search through search box it shows me nothing.

**Other information:**

- I put browser key where it required in code. Browser key I generate through this link https://code.google.com/apis/console
- Way of generate browser key Under credentials option--->Create new key--->Browser key.
- When I try to generate browser key it ask me for URL, then I it https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/ as url because it is given in code and second time I give nothing in URL section then google console also generate key and show *Any referer allower* under referer section. I tried both keys but search dialog box not show any suggestion.
- When I try to generate
- I also use android map API key in maninfest.
- Logcat showing some error during loading of map on emulator but it did not give any problem to load map. Map showing successfully.
- Map is showing on Emulater but search in not working.+
- I am not put map API key and browser key in code when I post this question but I used them during execution of code.
- I also tried this on real phone but problem is same.
- I also tried other related tutorial from this site but search through dialog is not working for me.
  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/

  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/selecting-google-place-from-autocompletetextview-and-marking-in-google-map-android-api-v2/ 

  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

I want to show suggestion when user try to input location address in auto complete box. So how to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

**Code**

MainActivity.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

    handleIntent(getIntent());  


}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)){
        doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){
        getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
    }

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void doSearch(String query){        
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("query", query);     
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
}

private void getPlace(String query){        
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("query", query);     
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_search:    
            onSearchRequested();
            break;
    }   
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle query) {
    CursorLoader cLoader = null;
    if(arg0==0)
        cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.SEARCH_URI, null, null, new String[]{ query.getString("query") }, null);
    else if(arg0==1)
        cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.DETAILS_URI, null, null, new String[]{ query.getString("query") }, null);
    return cLoader;

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) { 
    showLocations(c);       
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

private void showLocations(Cursor c){
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = null;
    LatLng position = null;
    mGoogleMap.clear();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        position = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(1)),Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)));
        markerOptions.position(position);
        markerOptions.title(c.getString(0));
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
    if(position!=null){
        CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraPosition);           
    }
}       
}
```

PlaceDetailsJSONParser.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PlaceDetailsJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

    Double lat = Double.valueOf(0);
    Double lng = Double.valueOf(0);
    String formattedAddress = "";

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    try {           
        lat = (Double)jObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lat");
        lng = (Double)jObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lng");
        formattedAddress = (String) jObject.getJSONObject("result").get("formatted_address");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }catch(Exception e){            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    hm.put("lat", Double.toString(lat));
    hm.put("lng", Double.toString(lng));
    hm.put("formatted_address",formattedAddress);

    list.add(hm);

    return list;
}   
}
```

PlaceJSONParser.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PlaceJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

    JSONArray jPlaces = null;
    try {           
        /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
        jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("predictions");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
     * where each json object represent a place
     */
    return getPlaces(jPlaces);
}


private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
    int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> place = null;   

    /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
    for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
        try {
            /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
            place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
            placesList.add(place);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return placesList;
}

/** Parsing the Place JSON object */
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

    HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String id="";
    String reference="";
    String description="";      

    try {

        description = jPlace.getString("description");          
        id = jPlace.getString("id");
        reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

        place.put("description", description);
        place.put("_id",id);
        place.put("reference",reference);

    } catch (JSONException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return place;
}
}
```

PlaceProvider.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class PlaceProvider extends ContentProvider {

public static final String AUTHORITY = "in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.PlaceProvider"; 

public static final Uri SEARCH_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/search");

public static final Uri DETAILS_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/details");

private static final int SEARCH = 1;    
private static final int SUGGESTIONS = 2;
private static final int DETAILS = 3;

// Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
String mKey = "key=YOUR_BROWSER_KEY";

// Defines a set of uris allowed with this content provider
private static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();    

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

    UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    // URI for "Go" button
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "search", SEARCH );

    // URI for suggestions in Search Dialog
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,SUGGESTIONS);

    // URI for Details
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "details",DETAILS);


    return uriMatcher;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor c = null;


    PlaceJSONParser parser = new PlaceJSONParser();
    PlaceDetailsJSONParser detailsParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();

    String jsonString = "";
    String jsonPlaceDetails = "";

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> detailsList = null;

    MatrixCursor mCursor = null;

    switch(mUriMatcher.match(uri)){
    case SEARCH:
        // Defining a cursor object with columns description, lat and lng
        mCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "description","lat","lng" });

        // Create a parser object to parse places in JSON format
        parser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        // Create a parser object to parse place details in JSON format
        detailsParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();

        // Get Places from Google Places API
        jsonString = getPlaces(selectionArgs); 
        try {
            // Parse the places ( JSON => List )
            list  = parser.parse(new JSONObject(jsonString));

            // Finding latitude and longitude for each places using Google Places Details API
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hMap = (HashMap<String, String>) list.get(i);

                detailsParser =new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();

                // Get Place details
                jsonPlaceDetails  = getPlaceDetails(hMap.get("reference"));

                // Parse the details ( JSON => List )
                detailsList = detailsParser.parse(new JSONObject(jsonPlaceDetails));

                // Creating cursor object with places
                for(int j=0;j<detailsList.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String, String> hMapDetails = detailsList.get(j);

                    // Adding place details to cursor
                    mCursor.addRow(new String[]{ hMap.get("description") , hMapDetails.get("lat") , hMapDetails.get("lng") });
                }

            }               
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c = mCursor;
        break;

    case SUGGESTIONS :          

        // Defining a cursor object with columns id, SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA
        mCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA }  );

        // Creating a parser object to parse places in JSON format
        parser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        // Get Places from Google Places API
        jsonString = getPlaces(selectionArgs);      

        try {
            // Parse the places ( JSON => List )
            list  = parser.parse(new JSONObject(jsonString));

            // Creating cursor object with places
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hMap = (HashMap<String, String>) list.get(i);

                // Adding place details to cursor
                mCursor.addRow(new String[] { Integer.toString(i), hMap.get("description"), hMap.get("reference") });               
            }               
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c = mCursor;
        break;

    case DETAILS :
        // Defining a cursor object with columns description, lat and lng
        mCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "description","lat","lng" });

        detailsParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();
        jsonPlaceDetails  = getPlaceDetails(selectionArgs[0]);
        try {
            detailsList = detailsParser.parse(new JSONObject(jsonPlaceDetails));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int j=0;j<detailsList.size();j++){
            HashMap<String, String> hMapDetails = detailsList.get(j);               
            mCursor.addRow(new String[]{ hMapDetails.get("formatted_address") , hMapDetails.get("lat") , hMapDetails.get("lng") });
        }
        c = mCursor;
        break;


    }       

    return c;
}


@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}


private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref){


    // reference of place
    String reference = "reference="+ref;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = reference+"&"+sensor+"&"+mKey;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}

private String getPlacesUrl(String qry){    


    try {
        qry = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(qry, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";


    // place type to be searched
    String types = "types=geocode";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = qry+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+mKey;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";    


    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;        

    return url;

}


private String getPlaces(String[] params){
    // For storing data from web service
    String data = "";
    String url = getPlacesUrl(params[0]);
    try{
        // Fetching the data from web service in background
        data = downloadUrl(url);
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
    }
    return data;        
}

private String getPlaceDetails(String reference){
    String data = "";
    String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl(reference);
    try {
        data = downloadUrl(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return data;
}   
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<!-- Protect the map component of the application using application signature -->
<permission 
    android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<!--  Allows to receive map -->
<uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) 
to determine the device's location to within a very small area -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Allows to contact Google Serves -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- Google Maps Android API V2 requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Points to searchable activity -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />

        <!-- Points to searchable meta data -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>            

    </activity>


    <provider 
        android:name=".PlaceProvider"
        android:authorities="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.PlaceProvider"
        android:exported="false" />


    <!-- Specifies the Android API Key, which is obtained from Google API Console -->
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY" />

</application>



</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
04-17 05:23:22.709: D/PackageBroadcastService(1518): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2
04-17 05:23:22.779: E/Icing(1518): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent due to initialization failure.
04-17 05:23:22.779: I/PeopleContactsSync(1518): CP2 sync disabled
04-17 05:23:23.849: I/MultiDex(2227): load(/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, forceReload=false)
04-17 05:23:24.059: D/dalvikvm(2227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 187K, 10% free 3047K/3356K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
04-17 05:23:24.059: I/MultiDex(2227): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip
04-17 05:23:24.059: I/MultiDex(2227): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip of size 1547068
04-17 05:23:25.119: D/dalvikvm(2227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 354K, 13% free 3204K/3680K, paused 75ms, total 76ms
04-17 05:23:35.429: I/MultiDex(2288): load(/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, forceReload=false)
04-17 05:23:35.579: D/dalvikvm(2288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 184K, 10% free 3053K/3356K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
04-17 05:23:35.599: I/MultiDex(2288): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip
04-17 05:23:35.609: I/MultiDex(2288): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip of size 1547068
04-17 05:23:35.649: D/PackageBroadcastService(2288): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
04-17 05:23:35.649: I/PackageBroadcastService(2288): Null package name or gms related package.  Ignoreing.
04-17 05:23:35.699: D/dalvikvm(2288): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libAppDataSearch.so 0xb2fd39d8, skipping init
04-17 05:23:35.699: E/Icing(2288): Native load error: Version mismatch 4323070 vs 4323030
04-17 05:23:36.019: I/Icing(2288): Storage manager: low false usage 9.34KB avail 122.16MB capacity 167.55MB
04-17 05:23:36.179: D/dalvikvm(2288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 355K, 13% free 3195K/3672K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
04-17 05:23:36.199: E/Icing(2288): Error initializing, resetting corpora: Could not create native index
04-17 05:23:36.209: E/Icing(2288): Internal init failed
04-17 05:23:36.209: E/Icing(2288): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED intent due to initialization failure.
```

Comment: did you find a solution ? I'm getting same error

Answer (score 1):

For the error regarding maps api,

You don't need to use:

```
<permission 
android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationsearchdialogv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<!--  Allows to receive map -->
```

Instead use this below your application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

As provided here,

[A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014222/a-required-meta-data-tag-in-your-apps-androidmanifest-xml-does-not-exist)

Regarding places and autocomplete try this perhaps,

https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android