# I can't use adMob in my App

Tags: android, admob

When I add the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F0F8FF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvHienThi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />
```

it show me :"No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package '....'"
How can I fix it ? Please help me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Replace **/res/** with **/lib/** in your custom layout nampespace

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

will be

```
 xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass"
```

i hope it help :)

Comment: hi sakikumar , i post the new error in my comment below . please check it , help me. Thank you !

Comment: Refer this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014222/a-required-meta-data-tag-in-your-apps-androidmanifest-xml-does-not-exist

Comment: Hi sakikumar , Thanks you.

Comment: I tried it , but it show me : 
http://i1277.photobucket.com/albums/y495/minkun9x/Untitled_zps18m4rosq.jpg

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package.name"
```

replacing "your.package.name" with your actual package name

Comment: Hi , I tried it . And I see a new problem : http://s1277.photobucket.com/user/minkun9x/media/Untitled_zps18m4rosq.jpg.html

Please help me . Thank you !