# Android instrumentation test errors due to com.google.android.gms.version meta data

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-camera, android-vision

I am attempting to write an instrumentation test for my Android app. When I run my test, and it hits the section of my code that attempts to use the  **com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector** library, the test framework throws the follow error:

```
A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

However, my AndroidManifest.xml already does contain that exact meta data tag, right here:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="NeuralEye-FaceID-2"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="face" />
```

What am I missing? My instrumented test looks something like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class FeatureExtractionTest {


    public FeatureExtraction mFeatureExtraction;

    public ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> skipList = new ConcurrentSkipListSet();

    @Before
    public void createFeatureExtraction() {
        mFeatureExtraction = new FeatureExtraction();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetFeatures() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("new.txt");
        Context ctx = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        mFeatureExtraction.getFeatures(file, skipList, ctx);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: adding build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tuan.search"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.5 "
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/opencsv-3.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I have already found a miriad of SO answers that all say add the meta-data tag to the manifest ([this one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014222/a-required-meta-data-tag-in-your-apps-androidmanifest-xml-does-not-exist)), however I already have it added and the test still will not run past the FaceDetector library.

Comment: Do not add `google_play_services_version`. It will be automatically added via the google play services AAR.

Comment: @JaredBurrows can you clarify? i have tried removing the <meta-data> tag completely and also tried just removing the "android:value" attribute and in both instances i still receive the same error when the test runs.

Comment: Show the build.gradle.

Comment: @JaredBurrows added build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the issue**

The test runner context does not have a manifest file. I needed to pass the correct context into the method i was testing. My test now looks like this (note the swap to **getTargetContext**):

```
@Test
public void testGetFeatures() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("new.txt");
    Context ctx = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    mFeatureExtraction.getFeatures(file, skipList, ctx);
}
```

FaceDetector was able to be initialized. Now I can finish actually implementing my test. Hopefully this helps someone.

Props to [this random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35766746/3934617), the list of context's is what helped me.

Comment: Nice, it looks like you figured it out.